# How to create a window in tauri with kiosk mode? (mac os, windows os)

Tags: kiosk, tauri

In electron, I can easily create a **kiosk window** by just adding a param `kiosk: true`.
But in tauri, is there any way to achieve that? I searched their official doc and couldn't find any.

Note: Here I'm referring to creating a window in fullscreen without topbar/ header and borders and it prevents the users to interact with other OS functionalities unless the user exists/ closes the app.

Answer (score 1):

In tauri.conf.json you can find and modify window params like

```
"windows": [
  {
    "fullscreen": true,
    "height": 600,
    "resizable": true,
    "title": "main",
    "width": 800,
    "alwaysOnTop": true,
    "maximized": false,
    "decorations": false
  }
]
```

for mas details read this: https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/window/#windowmanager

Comment: it will probably work on windows as expected. (+1 for that) but this is not a kiosk. it just does what the property says.
On macs, the top bar and dock can still be accessible by hovering the top and bottom edges.

any ideas for macs? on macs, in kiosk mode, it also hides the dock and top bar.

Comment: @emranio on my mac, kiosk mode in chrome also does not disable the appearance of panels and works like normal full screen mode.

Comment: I contacted tauri developers, and they said, currently it doesn't the feature.